# $k$-dimensional faces of an $n$-dimensional cube

Tags: generating-functions, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I want to find a formula that shows the number of $k$-dimensional faces of an $n$-dimensional cube. By internet I found that this formula has a generating function, $(x+2)^n$, where the formula is the coefficient of $x^k$. However, I still don't understand why this method works. Any explanation?

Edit: Now I need to find its number of inner diagonals and number of hyperplanes of symmetries. Inner diagonals are between vertices that are symmetric to each other with respect to the centre of the cube. I think each vertex has only one centre-symmetric vertex so the number of inner diagonals is $2^{n-1}$, namely half of the vertice number. What does "hyperplanes of symmetries" mean?

Comment: It's probably easier to understand combinatorially than as a generating function. Vertices are identified by an $n$-vector, each element of which has $2$ choices, so there are $2^n$ vertices. Edges are identified by choosing a single dimension along which the edge will stretch, along with an $n-1$-vector for the starting point, so there are $\binom{n}{1}2^{n-1}$ edges. Flat faces are identified by choosing two dimensions for the span of the face, along with an $n-2$-vector for the starting point, so there are $\binom{n}{2}2^{n-2}$ flat faces. Etc.

Comment: Let me know if that's clear enough. If not, I'll expand it into a full answer.

Comment: @BrianTung What do you mean by "vertices are identified by an $n$-vector"? I need more elaboration here.

Comment: I posted a proof in [this 29 August 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/W_WDXmUxNGU/m/ZaL7VJc9hfgJ).